# How to remove a Coefficient of (1) from SymPy symbolic expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to remove any coefficient that is equal to 1 in sympy symbolic expression , for example:
I want `1.0x**2` to be `x**2` , Is there anyway to do it ?
Also if possible to round integers , for example `2.0x**2` to be `2*x**2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `nsimplify`:

```
In [4]: nsimplify(2.0*x**2)
Out[4]: 
   2
2⋅x
```

in a Python shell

```py
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.nsimplify("1.0*x**2")
x**2
>>> sympy.nsimplify("2.0*x**2")
2*x**2
```